# How to put a decent snubber to the MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, high-voltage, protection, snubber

I am trying to make a soft starter for an inverter to make the turn on process as a yield curve like the one in the photo:[image]

so I used this circuit :[image]

however, the problem is still visible in the turning off process I do need a Snubber circuit(due to the fact that the inverter can act as Capacitive or Inductive load) so I need a way to dump the excess of the energy to protect the MOSFET.

Note:

-input current would be approx of 40A

-highest power dissipation is 1000W

- Zener is used to protect the MOSFET and make the Vgs less than 20V
- MOSFET rise time using the RC circuit is approximately 2 seconds

Edit:
MCU 0V states for low output to drive the pnp transistor

R2 which is 600mΩ represents the inverter which draws approximately 40A

Comment: It all depends what input filter has your inverter. If inverter has a proper input filtering maybe you don't need a snubber. Btw, I would consider to make a better filter than dissipating snubber. Also be careful about holding the mosfet under 1000W in linear region too much time.

Comment: can you please explain more?  why is it a filter problem? and what is the problem if the MOSFET been in linear region?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not what a snubber is for. A snubber is to dissipate the energy in short, unwanted spikes.

What you need is PWM. Drive your circuit with a Pulse Width Modulated signal, starting at 0 % duty cycle and slowly increasing to 100 % duty cycle. If the load is inductive, place a diode across it to carry the load current during the short periods when the MOSFET is off.

For that to work, you must remove that low pass filter (R1 and C1).

---

By the way, you can't drive that "MCU 0 V" with a signal from a microcontroller. Instead, drive the gate of that MOSFET with a gate driver IC powered by a 12 V supply.

Comment: I thought of making it simple by using RC which would gradually increases the voltage to drive the MOSFET.

Would just a flyback diode solve the inverter problem?if so how many amps and voltage should that diode be?

Comment: "I thought of making it simple by using RC which would gradually increases the voltage to drive the MOSFET." At 40 A & 24 V? No way! That MOSFET will glow like a light bulb! Believe me, PWM is the only practical way to do what you want.

Comment: Maybe we should step back and discuss this instead: What is the **ultimate** problem you need to solve? Why do you think you need a  a soft starter for an inverter?  See: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I need the soft starter to limit the inrush current, because it will draw more than 100amps during startup due to capacitors charging. If you may please tell me why is it better using PWM rather than RC?

Comment: Man! Why didn't you say that in the first place? You led us on a wild goose chase needlessly. What you need is "precharge", not "soft start". Do this. 1) Delete this question; 2) Start a new question; 3) Ask: "How do I implement precharge for a 24 V, 1 kW inverter?" Also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=precharge+inverter

Comment: The German word is "Vorladeschaltungen".

Comment: ah ok guess I need to know more names

Comment: Vielen Dank für ihre Helfen :D